# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable and renaming files

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working with Python 3.5 and trying to follow along the udacity course and teach myself python but having an issue getting a function to work as intended.

Code:

```
import os 
import re

def rename_file():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\mdvek\Desktop\Pyton Secret Message\prank")
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\mdvek\Desktop\Pyton Secret Message\prank")
    print (saved_path)
    for file_name in file_list:
        file_name = re.sub('[0-9]','', file_name)

    for file_name in file_list:    
        os.rename(file_name, re.sub('[0-9]','', file_name))
        os.chdir(saved_path)

rename_file()
```

Error:

```
File "C:/Users/mdvek/Desktop/Pyton Secret Message/prank/untitled0.py", line 14, in rename_file
    os.rename(file_name, re.sub('[0-9]','', file_name))

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you have a variable name that matches a function you are trying to perform.

Comment: I don't see anything here that could have caused that. Did you remove anything from your code when you posted this?

Comment: This was a straight copy and paste. I am thinking os.rename can not take a string inside it and I need to define it differently os.rename(input, output)

Comment: There's something wrong. What do you see if you add `print(os.rename)` and `print(re.sub)` before your second for loop?

Comment: Print(re.sub) has the correct output im looking for print(os.rename) is not working

Comment: Seems my second loop is definitly the issue

Comment: @Mdveke06 So on my system, it runs just fine and renames the files. First, start with getting rid of that first `for` loop. You don't do anything in there. Next, comment out everything in the second `for` loop and simply `print()` each of the `file_name` to make sure they are valid.

Comment: As soon as I get home I will try it again! I appreciate the help

Comment: @pstatix so I ran the code in console vs spyder and it worked! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Mdveke06 you should answer your own question and accept it, so that it has an answer.